# What are the best CS PhD programs in Europe?

Tags: phd, europe

In the United States, there is a clear ranking for universities and almost all universities offer PhD programs. Unlikely, not all universities in Europe do so.

I'm asking, what are the best Computer Science PhD programs offered in Europe? I plan to specialize in data mining/machine learning.

Comment: Machine learning is still quite broad (statistics, optimization, kernel methods, rule based approaches, bioinformatics, ...). You could try to find out what universities/departments the gurus in your specific field of interest are associated to.

Comment: There might be reason why there isn't a clear ranking, perhaps because such a ranking does not make sense, especially considering the diversity of the programs offered in different countries. You might have to find on your own what's the best *for you*.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] guidelines, we don't recommend specific universities/programs here.

Answer (score 7):

> In the United States, there is a clear ranking for universities and almost all universities offer PhD programs. Unlikely, not all universities in Europe do so.

If you're looking for global University rankings, you can find various versions with dubious methodologies out there on the Web. For example, one of the more famous of these is the [QS World University Rankings](http://www.topuniversities.com/subject-rankings). Again though, these rankings are dubious at best ... the hint being that they present the "quality" of a university as a single dimension when the "quality" of a university has high dimensionality.

> what are the best Computer Science PhD programs offered in Europe?

This is an almost completely different question. The best PhD programme is a combination of three simple things:

1. great supervisor that you get on well with and that lends you the time and expertise you need,
2. great topic in an emerging area you are interested in and with a healthy global research community,
3. great environment in a good office with the resources you need, a stable academic atmosphere and smart colleagues to bounce ideas off.

You can find such programmes in many reputable universities, even if they're not in the top 5 universities in Europe.

My advice would be to read some of the recent literature in the data mining area (e.g., SIGKDD, ICML, WSDM, ICDE, etc.), find the research group whose work most interests you and get in contact with a professor or postdoc there (or preferably find a mutual acquaintance to introduce you to him/her).

Finally, just to add that when you do a PhD, you have to start building your own reputation and not rely on the reputation of the university from which you received your PhD. You will be judged primarily by the work with your name on it. This is different from Bachelors and taught Masters.